# How to zoom out of an MKMapView without using didAddAnnotationViews?

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion, mkcoordinatespan

I am trying to find a way to do a zoom in and out via a button. If I put code within the method `didAddAnnotationViews`, it will set the initial zoom perfectly. I tried to get the zoom to change with the code below, but it keeps on crashing saying:

> Unrecognized Selector sent to Instance

How can I run this in an IBAction?

```
-(IBAction)ZoomIn:(MKCoordinateSpan)coordinateSpanWithMapView:(MKMapView *)mv centerCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location
{
   MKCoordinateRegion region;
   MKCoordinateSpan span; 
   span.latitudeDelta=0.05;
   span.longitudeDelta=0.05;
   location = mv.userLocation.coordinate;
   location = mv.userLocation.location.coordinate;
   region.span=span;
   region.center=location;
   [mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
   [mv regionThatFits:region]; 
};
```

Comment: can you please post full error message? Why are you taking "location" as a input when you are assigning it to userlocation coordinate?

Comment: Are you calling this method programmatically or is it hooked up to a button action in IB?  If IB then this method doesn't have the correct signature for a button action method.  If programmatically, show how you are calling it.

Comment: [MapView ZoomIn]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8768200. I removed the passing in of location and it still breaks

Comment: For a control action, the first parameter will be the control sending the message.  If the action is linked to a button, the first parameter will be the UIButton regardless of what parameter type or name you give in the method.  See [Cocoa Target-Action](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was trying to pass in the MapView in the IBAction line which I couldnt do. It did not know what to do with it. I referenced my MapView in the code instead of trying to pass it in the method...

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span; 
span.latitudeDelta=1.00;
span.longitudeDelta=1.00;
location = self.myMap.userLocation.coordinate;
location = self.myMap.userLocation.location.coordinate;
region.span=span;
region.center=location;
[self.LightUpMap setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[self.LightUpMap regionThatFits:region];
```

You can put this is any IBAction method now and it will zoom in to the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)zoomOut:btnMinus
{
  MKCoordinateSpan span = mapView.region.span;
  span.latitudeDelta = span.latitudeDelta * 2;
  span.longitudeDelta = span.longitudeDelta * 2;
  region.span=span;
  [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
  for(int j=2;j<count;j++)
  { places[j]=1;}
  [self filterAnnotations];  
}
```